# Doxygen - generating include graph - where is it supposed to be?

Tags: doxygen, doxywizard

I'm trying to find the interfile (i.e. which files include which other files) dependencies in a project using doxygen. Tbh, all I want is some pictures summarising that, but it doesn't seem to be possible to get just that.

My relevant settings are:

Wizard:

Output - only HTML

Diagrams - use dot tool from GraphViz (which is installed). Only Include dependency graphs is selected.

Expert:

Have dot: yes

INCLUDE_GRAPH: yes

DIRECTORY_GRAPH: yes (I can't find this either)

DOT_PATH: /usr/local/bin (dot is definitely found here)

Running this goes to completion, but no new images are produced. Not to be deterred, I visit index.html, but I see no way to see the include graphs. Where are they supposed to be?

Using the GUI wizard, on OS X 10.13.6

Comment: Are `ENABLE_PREPROCESSING` and `SEARCH_INCLUDES` set as well ?

Comment: Did you specify correctly the input paths ? (`INPUT` tag)

Answer (score 2):

If your files are not "Documented enteties" you have to change "Select the desired extraction mode" from "Documented entities only" to "All Entities".

Using the Doxygen GUI 1.8.17, this can be found under **Wizard->Mode->All Entities**

I think this is the same as changing EXTRACT_ALL option from NO to YES.